# Need help in understanding Recursion in the given program

Tags: java, recursion

Okay the output of this program is

```
hello3
hello2
hello1

0
1
2
```

I need an explanation after mymethod(--counter) and why does the output come out as 0, 1, 2 and not 3, 2, 1 (P.S. the value of int counter is '3')

```
public void mymethod(int counter){
    if(counter==0)
        System.out.println("");
    else{
        System.out.println("hello" + counter);
        mymethod(--counter);
        System.out.println(" " +counter);
    }

}
```

`

Comment: trace through the recursion. note that one is before the call and the other is after

Comment: What int counter are you starting with?  3, I assume?

Comment: YES 3 omg I forgot to mention that

Comment: Use a debugging tool. It'd be much clearer to you that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you get hello3 as first output, you probably passed in 3 as the argument the first time you invoked myMethod():

```
//Imagine invoking myMethod() from the main..
public static void main(String[] args){
    myMethod(3);

}
```

Invoke **myMethod(3)** causes the following:

```
public void mymethod(3){
    if(counter==0)
        System.out.println("");
    else{                                       // <=== came into else block
        System.out.println("hello" + counter);  // <=== print "hello3"
        mymethod(--counter);                    // <=== invoke myMethod(2)
        System.out.println(" " +counter);
    }
}
```

Invoke **myMethod(2)** causes the following:

```
public void mymethod(2){
    if(counter==0)
        System.out.println("");
    else{                                       // <=== came into else block
        System.out.println("hello" + counter);  // <=== print "hello2"
        mymethod(--counter);                    // <=== invoke myMethod(1)
        System.out.println(" " +counter);
    }
}
```

Invoke **myMethod(1)** causes the following:

```
public void mymethod(1){
    if(counter==0)
        System.out.println("");
    else{                                       // <=== came into else block
        System.out.println("hello" + counter);  // <=== print "hello1"
        mymethod(--counter);                    // <=== invoke myMethod(0)
        System.out.println(" " +counter);
    }
}
```

Invoke **myMethod(0)** causes the following:

```
public void mymethod(0){
    if(counter==0)                              // <=== if-condition is true
        System.out.println("");                 // <=== print newline
    else{                                       
        System.out.println("hello" + counter);  
        mymethod(--counter);                    
        System.out.println(" " +counter);
    }
} // <=== exit method (goes back to last point where this myMethod(0) was callled)
```

Continue from ***myMethod(1)***:

```
public void mymethod(1){
    if(counter==0)
        System.out.println("");
    else{                                       
        System.out.println("hello" + counter);  
        mymethod(--counter);                    // <=== this point invoked myMethod(0)
        System.out.println(" " +counter);       // <=== continue from here (print " " + 0)
    }
} // <=== exit method (goes back to last point where this myMethod(1) was called
```

Continue from ***myMethod(2)***:

```
public void mymethod(2){
    if(counter==0)
        System.out.println("");
    else{                                       
        System.out.println("hello" + counter);  
        mymethod(--counter);                    // <=== this point invoked myMethod(1)
        System.out.println(" " +counter);       // <=== continue from here (print " " + 1)
    }
} // <=== exit method (goes back to last point where this myMethod(2) was called
```

Continue from ***myMethod(3)***:

```
public void mymethod(3){
    if(counter==0)
        System.out.println("");
    else{                                       
        System.out.println("hello" + counter);  
        mymethod(--counter);                    // <=== this point invoked myMethod(2)
        System.out.println(" " +counter);       // <=== continue from here (print " " + 2)
    }
} // <=== exit method (goes back to last point where this myMethod(3) was called
```

Goes back to `main()`.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    myMethod(3);
    //<=== continue from this point
}
```

Comment: OMG this is a very detailed explanation and it really helped me visualize instantly! Thank you soo much for your effort and time!

Comment: @32sav Glad to help, everything should be clear now. This solution took me quite a while :P

Answer (score 2):

What happens during the recursion is that each time through the loop, it invokes itself with the argument decreased by one, until it gets to 0. So you have

- `mymethod(3)` invokes `mymethod(2)`
- this invokes `mymethod(1)`
- this invokes `mymethod(0)`

Now by this point, `mymethod(1)` is at the top of the stack. As the recursion is unwound, the methods finish in reverse order, so `mymethod(0)` finishes first, then `mymethod(1)`, and finally `mymethod(2)`.

Think of it like a stack of plates of different sizes: when you stack the plates up, you put them on from biggest to smallest; when you take them off again, you take them off from smallest to biggest.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me understand such a basic concept.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive functions can be tricky to visualize.

Think of the calling function as being on a stack, with the called function on top of it.  When the called function finally terminates and doesn't call another function, the program returns to the next function on the stack, which concludes and then returns to the next function on the stack, etc.

So, the line that prints "hello" + counter is called, and then the function calls `mymethod(--counter)`.  That whole process (getting down to `mymethod(0)` and back) has to happen before the second print statement.

So, your program prints hello3, hello2, and hello1, putting `mymethod(3)`, `mymethod(2)`, and `mymethod(1)` on the stack.  It gets to `mymethod(0)`, prints a blank string, and then returns to `mymethod(1)`, `mymethod(2)`, and `mymethod(3)` in that order.  In each case it prints `--counter`, which would be one less than the counter in the parameter.  Make sense?

Comment: So when function mymethod(int counter) does not return anymore values then the second function mymethod(--counter) starts unloading ?

Comment: When mymethod(0) is called, it doesn't call any other functions, so when it terminates the stack reverts to mymethod(1), which completes its final line, terminates, and the stack reverts to mymethod(2), etc.